# How I can play an array from sounds ? - Android

Tags: java, android, arrays, android-mediaplayer

I create an `Array` of sound and then I need to play them but I can hear just first sound :

This my `Array` :

```
public static class Marrays{
    public static String[] Zero(){
        String[] OK = new String[] {"num1.mp3" , "increment.amr", "num1.mp3"};
        return OK;
    }
}
```

And :

```
String[] a = Marrays.Zero();
```

And I use from above `array` :

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    try {
        AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(a[i]);
        mediaPlayer.stop();
        mediaPlayer.release();
        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
        mediaPlayer.prepare();
        mediaPlayer.start();
    } 
    catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  } 
    catch (IllegalStateException e) {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); } 
    catch (IOException e) { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
}
```

Comment: you should use multiple instance of mediaplayer i think, depend if you want to play all the list at the same time or one by one. (BTW, i think your can hear just the 'Last' sound)

Comment: I need to play them one by one .

Comment: you must read the documentation http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html because you need to know when a item stop to load the other item, and so on..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this :

```
if(count < 3){
    Main_Sound_mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            if(count <= 3){
            try {
                AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(a[count]);
                if (Main_Sound_mediaPlayer.isPlaying()==true ){
                    Main_Sound_mediaPlayer.stop();}
                Main_Sound_mediaPlayer.reset();
                Main_Sound_mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd .getLength());
                Main_Sound_mediaPlayer.prepare();
                Main_Sound_mediaPlayer.start();
            } 
            catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  } 
            catch (IllegalStateException e) {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); } 
            catch (IOException e) { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
            }
            count++ ;
        }
    });
    if (flag == true) {
        try {
            AssetFileDescriptor afd = getAssets().openFd(a[count]);
            if (Main_Sound_mediaPlayer.isPlaying()==true ){
                Main_Sound_mediaPlayer.stop();}
            Main_Sound_mediaPlayer.reset();
            Main_Sound_mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(),afd.getStartOffset(),afd.getLength());
            Main_Sound_mediaPlayer.prepare();
            Main_Sound_mediaPlayer.start();
        } 
        catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {  Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();  } 
        catch (IllegalStateException e) {Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); } 
        catch (IOException e) { Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();}
        flag = false;
    }
    count++ ;
}else {
    if (Main_Sound_mediaPlayer.isPlaying()==true ){
        Main_Sound_mediaPlayer.stop();}
    Main_Sound_mediaPlayer.reset();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should probably wait for each sound to finish playing, before you play the next one :

`mediaplayer.setOnCompletionListener` will allow you to create a listener where you can read the next sound. (Set a counter field to know witch sound to play.

Hope it helps!

Comment: should be 'setOnCompletionListener'